# Backup of saved Wi-Fi networks

Tags: wifi, backup

I am thinking to switch from WP7.8 to WP8. There are many Wi-Fi networks which are saved in my mobile. Is it able to backup these along with their information like password, proxy etc and restore the backup on new phone (WP 8).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but there isn't. Even if you had a WP8 (that was backup features) I think password protected configurations are not save to the cloud.

**Edit**: Unfortunately there is no APIs for developers make an app to improve those behaviors.

Comment: can we do this programmatically? making an app?

Comment: Programmers generally don't have access to internal phone settings and configuration such as this.